# Create functions inside loop mantaining index value

Tags: javascript, loops, dynamic-programming

I have an object that has an option to create a function on certain event, and I want to create many instances of this object with a loop:

```
var dragging;
var dragObj = new Array();
for(i=0; i<20; i++){
   dragObj[i] = new Draggy('btn_id_'+i, {
        restrictY:false, 
        restrictX:false,
        onChange: function(){
            dragging = i;
            console.log(dragObj[i].position);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I select elements with id 'btn_id_'+i that obtains the draggy object, this allows elements to be dragged and onChange (drag) I can execute a function, in this case I just want to trace in the console the position of the element being dragged and save into a variable the index of the element that is being dragged.

This doesn't work since "`onChange`" will be executed in a certain moment when the loop is done and `i` is equal to tha last index of my loop (20).

How can I execute the loop allowing the function inside "`onChange`" to maintain the value of `i` at the moment when the loop created the function.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/750495/184595